# Different FEDFUND INDEX use for Basis swap with LIBOR and SOFR

Tags: interest-rate-swap, basis

I am trying to understand the compounding in Basis Swap. I had 2 type of basis swap trade as below

1. USD SOFR FF BASIS LCH – compounded FF (USD-Federal Funds-H.15-OIS-COMPOUND)
2. USD LIBOR 3M FF 3M BASIS – weighted FF (USD-Federal Funds-H.15)

**Could somebody explain here why we are using different Fed Fund index here for SOFR and LIBOR?**

Thanks so much!